# Exchange 2013 Spam / Junk Email

Tags: exchange, spam, exchange-2013

We have an Exchange 2013 installation ready to go live in our organization. Due to budget restraints, our spam solution will be added in 3-6 months. We are going to use the built-in Anti-spam and malware solutions that are built into Exchange 2013 for the time.
We would like to setup a quarantine mailbox for all spam (which can be done with PS) but we would also like to disable all users junk email folders in Outlook. How can we disable all oulook junk email folder settings without the use of GP?

Comment: `How can we disable all oulook junk email folder settings without the use of GP?` Manually.  Why on earth would you not use Group Policy for this?

Comment: Group Policies are for the lazy admins. :O

Comment: Why would you care to disable the junk folder anyway?  It's not like it's some kind of override on Exchange's built-in settings, and users know what it's there for and can tweak it accordingly for themselves.

Comment: I would have to assume that the selected antispam option replaces or duplicates the Junk Folder's capability, and this measure is meant to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1):

For on-premises Exchange 2013, you can set some specific spam-handling options, on a per-mailbox basis.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981(v=exchg.150).aspx

Items of note

- `AntiSpamBypassEnabled` (for your Spam Quarantine idea?)
- `SCLJunkEnabled` (Items meeting SCL threshold ((See next)) go to Junk
  Email folder, Boolean.)
- `SCLJunkThreshold`(Set SCL threshold for    sending items to junk 
  ((See above)).)

I do not have experience with any of these, so test before use in production. ;)

To disable Junk Email folder in Outlook, you must use Group Policy, or customize the Office install.  Of those two, Group Policy is the easier and superior solution.